# Assigning Definite Type In Switch Statement

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Okay, there are similar questions here but I was not able to find one specific to my case, or I didnt understand some.
I will explain it and then show the code:

1.I have a react component that takes a store as a prop.
2.This store have a "tab" prop which is a string and can be either "points" or "segments" or "tags"
3.The store also have a points, segments or tags array, which are respectively types Array, Array and Array.
4.In my component I need to have a variable called "selectedEntity" that can either of these types, so what I did was declare it without typing and then, inside a switch statement, assign it to the proper value and type.
Problem is that typescript is complaining. Even after assignment and even with type assertion, typescrit still says that 'selectedEntity' is of type any.

Code:

```
const TagCustomization: React.FC<PropsType> = ({ store, curr }) => {

let selectedEntities;
let thisEntity;
let thisTag;

useEffect(() => {
  switch (store.tab) {
    case "points":
      selectedEntities = store.points.filter(
        (point) => point.selected,
      ) as Array<Tpoint>; //<--I am SURE this will be of type Array<Tponto>
      thisEntity = selectedEntities[curr] as Tpoint;
      thisTag = store.tags.find(
        (tag) => tag.id == thisEntity.id, //<--Typescript still errors that "Variable 'thisEntity' implicitly has an 'any' type.".
      );
      break;
    //SAME HAPPENS BELOW
    case "segments":
      selectedEntities = store.segments.filter(
        (seg) => seg.selected,
      ) as Array<Tsegment>;
      thisEntity = selectedEntities[curr] as Tsegment;
      thisTag = store.tags.find(
        (tag) => tag.id == thisEntity.id,
      );
      break;
    case "tags":
      selectedEntities = store.tags.filter(
        (tag) => tag.selected,
      ) as Array<Ttag>;
      thisEntity = selectedEntities[curr] as Ttag;
      thisTag = thisEntity;
      break;
    }
  }
}, [store.tab, curr]);

...
```

So whats going on and how can I definetely tell typescript the type of selectedEntities and thisEntity inside and after the switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS uses the declared (implicit `any`) type of `thisEntity` rather than that of the assigned value (`Tponto`) because you're using it in a *callback* (the one passed to `find`). TypeScript doesn't make assumptions about the implementation of `find` and doesn't rule out that `thisEntity` may be reassigned to something other than a `Tponto` before or in between function calls.

You may read and store the id you want to compare to *before calling find* though.

```
switch (store.tab) {
  case 'points': { // lexical block to allow variable declaration
    ...
    thisEntity = selectedEntities[curr]
    const thisEntityId = thisEntity.id;
    thisTag = store.tags.find((tag) => tag.id == thisEntityId);
    break;
  }
  case 'segments':
    ...
}
```

That being said, it would be better to keep all relevant variables local to each case, not just the id, and use `React.useState` to store and update component state when the `store` and `curr` props change.

If what you're trying to do here is just to reduce the number of times these variables are calculated, consider using `useMemo` instead of `useEffect`, i.e.:

```
const { selectedEntities, thisEntity, thisTag } = useMemo(() => {
  let selectedEntities, thisEntity, thisTag;
  switch (store.tab) {
    case ... {
      selectedEntities = ...
      thisEntity = ...
      thisTag = ...
      break;
    }
    ...
  }
  // Types will probably be inferred as (Tpoint[]|Tsegment[]|Ttag[]) etc.
  return { selectedEntities, thisEntity, thisTag };
}, [store.tab, curr]);

// use variables here
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive explanation. It makes a little bit more sense now, despite it looking weird.
Thanks for the advice too, I was pondering on the pros and cons of using state and not just normal variables in this case, and I thought I didn't need state for it.
It seems that this is the case where TS actually forces you to write in a way that would not necessarly be easier to read or even more perfomant.

Comment: @DanielGuedes You don't need to use state if the values aren't used elsewhere in your component, but you definitely should not have a useEffect write to variables declared in the render function's scope - that'll cause unexpected behavior. For example, other effects dependent on those variables wouldn't be triggered because effects only execute after a re-render triggered by a *state update*. If you need mutable variables inside an effect, declare them inside the effect's scope.

Comment: If you declared and assigned `thisEntity` (and the other variables) as a local `const` inside the case block instead, you wouldn't even need to pull out its `id` first because it would no longer be of `any` type. The code I gave assumes you needed the variables for something outside the effect.

Comment: There's also `useMemo`, which may be what you actually want to use instead of `useEffect` here, if you just want to assign the variables based on props and reuse the previous render's value if `tab` and `curr` didn't change. I've updated the answer with an example. Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: Thanks again! I switched to useMemo as it was Indeed the case.